# Can PVC moulding be used indoors?

Tags: trim

I recently stumbled upon this some [PVC moulding](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Royal-Mouldings-5947-3-8-in-x-1-1-4-in-x-7-ft-PVC-Composite-Colonial-Stop-Espresso-Moudling-0594707067/202089978), I actually hadn't known they were making trim out of PVC. Is it designed just for outside, or can it be used indoors too? How do you attach it to interior wall?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We like it for bathrooms and other wet environments. It nails perfectly normally with an air nailer (usually 18g).

The only thing is that you can't cut it slowly, as it'll melt and you'll end up with a blobby mess at your cut. Cut briskly and all is fine.

Comment: ditto for "blobby mess".